# Use changing variable in loop in Powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, variables

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and tried to find a solution to simplify my script.

Problem: I need to update several fields with a number in the variable name in a loop. Now I did it using "if statement" (see below) but I need to update many fields and looking for an easier way.

Below the example script:

```
#START OF SCRIPT
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$field_value_1 = ""
$field_value_2 = ""
$field_value_3 = ""

$user_1 = "Dave"
$user_2 = "Chris"
$user_3 = "Bob"

for ($i=1;$i-le 3;$i++){

if($i -eq 1){$field_value_1 = Get-ADUser $user_1 | Select -Expand Name}
elseif($i -eq 2){$field_value_2 = Get-ADUser $user_2 | Select -Expand Name}
elseif($i -eq 3){$field_value_3 = Get-ADUser $user_3 | Select -Expand Name}
}

write-host "These are the values: $field_value_1, $field_value_2, $field_value_3"

#END OF SCRIPT
```

What I'm looking for is to add something like this in the loop instead of the if statements:

```
$field_value_$i = Get-ADUser $user_$i | Select -Expand Name
```

So basically that `$field_value_$i` translates into `$field_value_1` and on the next loop to `$field_value_2` etc. Same for the `$user_x` fields.

The result would be that in loop one, it would load the value from `$user_1` (Dave), lookup the Active Directory name (Dave Cross), and write it to the `$field_value_1` variable. On the next loop it would load the value from `$user_2` (Chris), lookup the Active Directory name (Chris Bowes), and write it to the `$field_value_2` variable and so on.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I had a look at Dynamic variables but could not figure out how to do it.

***UPDATE***
The way to get the info is to use arrays the next problem was to write the results to a text field on the form and that only works when using `iex`

```
Invoke-Expression  "`$textfield$i.Text = `$var[$i]"
```

This will use the $i in the command to pull the info from the array and also write it to the correct text field. You have to use the ` in order to read the $ as text. The Invoke_Expression will execute the full text command :-)

Comment: What wrong with arrays? `$users='Dave','Chris','Bob';$field_values=@($users|%{Get-ADUser $_ | Select -Expand Name})`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

I looked at arrays but I think it does not do what I need because pulling the information out of the array and to put it into the field_value_1, field_value_2 & field_value_3 variables, would pose the same issue.

The reason why I need them separately is because in the end, I will need to write those field_values into text fields on a form.

Apologies if I did not understand your post correctly.

Comment: I did some more testing and found a way using the array :-)

Comment: One step closer. Using: `$field_values[$i]`, you can use a changing variable to pull the information from the array.

Last step I'm looking for is something similar to write into the text fields like:

    `$Form_Textfield_$i.Text = $field_values[$i]`

But that `$Form_Textfield_$i` will fail of course...